# PayPal API Website integration with or without CURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, paypal

PayPals documentation is quite confusing:

I need to integrate PayPal API into my website so the customer can pay for a final sum. And im using the sandbox for testing.

Now, technically, i found two different methods of integrating the API:

1. Without curl - using header('location', $urlwithvars)
2. With curl https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/

Now what confuses me - is curl only used because you can do a POST call to the paypal server? Because using the first option i also get directed to the paypal procedure and get the JSON response successfully on my notification url.

Im using following library: https://github.com/jersonandyworks/Paypal-Library-by-RomyBlack

Is that enough or should i use the complete curl process like here http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php

So basically the main question: DO i have to use curl process or is the header-location-url idea enough?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library you're using is actually just using [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wps), not [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec).  That may be where part of your confusion comes from.  This isn't even hitting the actual API's.  Not sure if you care about that or not, but I personally prefer the full Express Checkout API as it provides a lot more options and freedom to integrate however you want.

I'd recommend you take a look at my [PHP Class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library), which has all of the actual API's built in.  I have a [CodeIgniter specific version](http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-adaptive-payments-pro-payflow-codeigniter-library/140/support) of it, too.  It will do all the API work for you and you can integrate pretty much all of their calls within minutes.